# Regarding SUMO Simulator Usage

Tags: sumo

Can SUMO Simulator be used to create a traffic scenario by adding number of vehicles,types of vehicles(car,truck,bus,etc) to create a traffic signal junction using SUMO,OMNet++,Veins Simulator?
Does anyone suggest what is the best place to learn these simulators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get started is probably the Veins tutorial http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/. SUMO offers some tutorials as well:
http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials

Comment: Thank you Sir.But I am already following it.But since recreating a real traffic scenarioin the SUMO simulator is a part of my project.I wanted to know how to proceed with it.

Comment: When you need a real world network, the best way to start is probably this: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials/OSMWebWizard

Comment: Okay.Thank you sir once again for your kind gesture.Any more help required, I shall add further.

Comment: Then please mark the question as solved. For further inquiries please also have a look at http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Contact

Comment: How to locate the files to be edited after generation or the scenario..?I am finding it difficult to locate the files as there is no new directory as such being created..

Comment: It is mentioned here where to look for the files: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials/OSMWebWizard#Where_to_go_from_here